# watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:101147] - up-board up² upsquared - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, freeze, watchdog

we are using an up-board up² (up-squared) in a headless configuration as an IoT device to control different hardware via local REST interfaces. Sometimes when a USB device gets faulty or is damaged, we are facing the above warning in /var/log/syslog and the system hangs / freezes. The watchdog detects the error, but the system comes back for a short moment and the CPU gets stuck again. My wish is, that the system reboots, as we cannot visit the servers and do cold reboot or power down and up again.

```
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162882] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:101147]
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162887] Modules linked in: dm_crypt wdat_wdt nls_iso8859_1 dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_soc_dmic intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio intel_rapl_common snd_soc_core intel_telemetry_pltdrv snd_compress ac97_bus intel_punit_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp snd_hda_core kvm_intel snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm rapl intel_cstate joydev pl2303 usbserial hid_multitouch snd_seq_midi leds_upboard snd_seq_midi_event 8250_dw cdc_acm snd_rawmidi intel_xhci_usb_role_switch roles snd_seq ti_adc128s052 industrialio snd_seq_device snd_timer snd mei_me mac_hid soundcore mei sch_fq_codel ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162929]  raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid hid mmc_block pinctrl_upboard spi_pxa2xx_platform dw_dmac dw_dmac_core dwc3 ulpi udc_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper upboard_fpga i2c_i801 sdhci_pci lpc_ich cqhci sdhci i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci intel_lpss_pci drm intel_lpss libahci dwc3_pci r8169 idma64 virt_dma realtek video pinctrl_broxton pinctrl_intel
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162966] CPU: 0 PID: 101147 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G        W         5.4.0-1-generic #0~upboard2-Ubuntu
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162967] Hardware name: AAEON UP-APL01/UP-APL01, BIOS UPA1AM52 08/04/2020
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162976] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162982] RIP: 0010:try_to_grab_pending+0x10e/0x160
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162985] Code: ef c6 07 00 0f 1f 40 00 49 8b 3c 24 57 9d 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 13 b8 fe ff ff ff 83 e2 14 48 83 fa 10 0f 84 32 ff ff ff f3 90 <b8> f5 ff ff ff 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 48 8d 7f 20 e8 3b 3f 07
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162986] RSP: 0018:ffffb4344243fa78 EFLAGS: 00000287 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162988] RAX: 00000000fffffffe RBX: ffff939f73c8f790 RCX: 0000000000000000
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162988] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000286
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162989] RBP: ffffb4344243fa98 R08: ffff939f70403b50 R09: ffff939f70403b78
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162990] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffff83c5d958 R12: ffffb4344243faa8
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162991] R13: ffff939f70e2a680 R14: ffffb4344243fac8 R15: ffffffff826be580
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162993] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff939f70e00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162994] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162995] CR2: 00007f0d8d050010 CR3: 000000003660a000 CR4: 00000000003406f0
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.162996] Call Trace:
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163003]  __cancel_work_timer+0x4a/0x1b0
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163006]  ? usb_kill_urb+0x50/0xc0
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163009]  cancel_work_sync+0x10/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163015]  acm_disconnect+0x110/0x200 [cdc_acm]
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163017]  usb_unbind_interface+0x7f/0x260
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163021]  device_release_driver_internal+0xec/0x1c0
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163022]  device_release_driver+0x12/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163025]  bus_remove_device+0xe1/0x150
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163027]  device_del+0x167/0x380
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163029]  usb_disable_device+0x9f/0x250
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163031]  usb_disconnect+0xc6/0x270
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163034]  hub_port_connect+0x81/0x990
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163036]  port_event+0x692/0x7f0
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163039]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163042]  hub_event+0x21e/0x3b0
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163044]  process_one_work+0x20f/0x400
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163046]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163048]  kthread+0x121/0x140
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163050]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163052]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
Apr  5 09:02:14 lunixo kernel: [65737.163053]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165333] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:101147]
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165335] Modules linked in: dm_crypt wdat_wdt nls_iso8859_1 dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_soc_dmic intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio intel_rapl_common snd_soc_core intel_telemetry_pltdrv snd_compress ac97_bus intel_punit_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp snd_hda_core kvm_intel snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm rapl intel_cstate joydev pl2303 usbserial hid_multitouch snd_seq_midi leds_upboard snd_seq_midi_event 8250_dw cdc_acm snd_rawmidi intel_xhci_usb_role_switch roles snd_seq ti_adc128s052 industrialio snd_seq_device snd_timer snd mei_me mac_hid soundcore mei sch_fq_codel ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165378]  raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid hid mmc_block pinctrl_upboard spi_pxa2xx_platform dw_dmac dw_dmac_core dwc3 ulpi udc_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper upboard_fpga i2c_i801 sdhci_pci lpc_ich cqhci sdhci i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci intel_lpss_pci drm intel_lpss libahci dwc3_pci r8169 idma64 virt_dma realtek video pinctrl_broxton pinctrl_intel
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165397] CPU: 0 PID: 101147 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G        W    L    5.4.0-1-generic #0~upboard2-Ubuntu
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165398] Hardware name: AAEON UP-APL01/UP-APL01, BIOS UPA1AM52 08/04/2020
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165402] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165404] RIP: 0010:try_to_grab_pending+0x10e/0x160
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165406] Code: ef c6 07 00 0f 1f 40 00 49 8b 3c 24 57 9d 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 13 b8 fe ff ff ff 83 e2 14 48 83 fa 10 0f 84 32 ff ff ff f3 90 <b8> f5 ff ff ff 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 48 8d 7f 20 e8 3b 3f 07
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165407] RSP: 0018:ffffb4344243fa78 EFLAGS: 00000287 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165408] RAX: 00000000fffffffe RBX: ffff939f73c8f790 RCX: 0000000000000000
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165409] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000286
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165410] RBP: ffffb4344243fa98 R08: ffff939f70403b50 R09: ffff939f70403b78
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165411] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffff83c5d958 R12: ffffb4344243faa8
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165412] R13: ffff939f70e2a680 R14: ffffb4344243fac8 R15: ffffffff826be580
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165414] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff939f70e00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165415] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165416] CR2: 00007f0d8d050010 CR3: 000000003660a000 CR4: 00000000003406f0
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165417] Call Trace:
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165419]  __cancel_work_timer+0x4a/0x1b0
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165421]  ? usb_kill_urb+0x50/0xc0
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165424]  cancel_work_sync+0x10/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165426]  acm_disconnect+0x110/0x200 [cdc_acm]
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165429]  usb_unbind_interface+0x7f/0x260
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165431]  device_release_driver_internal+0xec/0x1c0
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165432]  device_release_driver+0x12/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165435]  bus_remove_device+0xe1/0x150
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165436]  device_del+0x167/0x380
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165438]  usb_disable_device+0x9f/0x250
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165441]  usb_disconnect+0xc6/0x270
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165443]  hub_port_connect+0x81/0x990
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165445]  port_event+0x692/0x7f0
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165447]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165450]  hub_event+0x21e/0x3b0
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165452]  process_one_work+0x20f/0x400
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165454]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165456]  kthread+0x121/0x140
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165457]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165459]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
Apr  5 09:02:42 lunixo kernel: [65765.165461]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181684] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181689] rcu:  0-....: (15000 ticks this GP) idle=016/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=5054683/5054683 fqs=7500 
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181691]   (t=15001 jiffies g=10777525 q=2590)
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181693] NMI backtrace for cpu 0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181696] CPU: 0 PID: 101147 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G        W    L    5.4.0-1-generic #0~upboard2-Ubuntu
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181696] Hardware name: AAEON UP-APL01/UP-APL01, BIOS UPA1AM52 08/04/2020
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181699] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181700] Call Trace:
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181702]  <IRQ>
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181705]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x95
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181708]  nmi_cpu_backtrace+0x94/0xa0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181711]  ? lapic_can_unplug_cpu+0xb0/0xb0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181736]  nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xe7/0x130
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181738]  arch_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0x19/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181741]  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x9e/0xd6
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181743]  rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x508/0x770
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181747]  ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x60/0x60
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181749]  update_process_times+0x28/0x60
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181751]  tick_sched_handle+0x25/0x70
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181752]  tick_sched_timer+0x3c/0x80
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181754]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x10f/0x280
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181756]  hrtimer_interrupt+0xe7/0x240
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181759]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x6f/0x130
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181761]  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181762]  </IRQ>
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181764] RIP: 0010:try_to_grab_pending+0x10e/0x160
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181766] Code: ef c6 07 00 0f 1f 40 00 49 8b 3c 24 57 9d 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 13 b8 fe ff ff ff 83 e2 14 48 83 fa 10 0f 84 32 ff ff ff f3 90 <b8> f5 ff ff ff 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 48 8d 7f 20 e8 3b 3f 07
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181767] RSP: 0018:ffffb4344243fa78 EFLAGS: 00000287 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181768] RAX: 00000000fffffffe RBX: ffff939f73c8f790 RCX: 0000000000000000
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181769] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000286
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181770] RBP: ffffb4344243fa98 R08: ffff939f70403b50 R09: ffff939f70403b78
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181771] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffff83c5d958 R12: ffffb4344243faa8
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181772] R13: ffff939f70e2a680 R14: ffffb4344243fac8 R15: ffffffff826be580
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181773]  ? work_busy+0x90/0x90
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181776]  __cancel_work_timer+0x4a/0x1b0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181778]  ? usb_kill_urb+0x50/0xc0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181780]  cancel_work_sync+0x10/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181782]  acm_disconnect+0x110/0x200 [cdc_acm]
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181784]  usb_unbind_interface+0x7f/0x260
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181786]  device_release_driver_internal+0xec/0x1c0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181788]  device_release_driver+0x12/0x20
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181790]  bus_remove_device+0xe1/0x150
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181792]  device_del+0x167/0x380
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181794]  usb_disable_device+0x9f/0x250
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181796]  usb_disconnect+0xc6/0x270
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181798]  hub_port_connect+0x81/0x990
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181800]  port_event+0x692/0x7f0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181802]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181805]  hub_event+0x21e/0x3b0
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181807]  process_one_work+0x20f/0x400
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181808]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181810]  kthread+0x121/0x140
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181812]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181814]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
Apr  5 09:02:46 lunixo kernel: [65769.181815]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Apr  5 09:03:14 lunixo kernel: [65797.168123] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/0:2:101147]
```

This is my /etc/watchdog.conf :

```
#ping                   = 172.31.14.1
#ping                   = 172.26.1.255
#interface              = eth0
#file                   = /var/log/messages
#change                 = 1407

# Uncomment to enable test. Setting one of these values to '0' disables it.
# These values will hopefully never reboot your machine during normal use
# (if your machine is really hung, the loadavg will go much higher than 25)
#max-load-1             = 24
#max-load-5             = 18
#max-load-15            = 12

# Note that this is the number of pages!
# To get the real size, check how large the pagesize is on your machine.
#min-memory             = 1
#allocatable-memory     = 1

#repair-binary          = /usr/sbin/repair
#repair-timeout         = 60
#test-binary            =
#test-timeout           = 60

# The retry-timeout and repair limit are used to handle errors in a more robust
# manner. Errors must persist for longer than retry-timeout to action a repair
# or reboot, and if repair-maximum attempts are made without the test passing a
# reboot is initiated anyway.
#retry-timeout          = 60
#repair-maximum         = 1

watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog

# Defaults compiled into the binary
#temperature-sensor     =
#max-temperature        = 90

# Defaults compiled into the binary
#admin                  = root
#interval               = 1
#logtick                = 1
#log-dir                = /var/log/watchdog

# This greatly decreases the chance that watchdog won't be scheduled before
# your machine is really loaded
realtime                = yes
priority                = 1

# Check if rsyslogd is still running by enabling the following line
#pidfile                = /var/run/rsyslogd.pid
```

Uncommentig #file doesn't help, as the system is still running and writing contents there. Does anyone know how to force the system to reboot automatically, when there's this soft-lockup CPU#0 stuck?

This is /proc/interrupts

```
           CPU0       CPU1
   0:          9          0  IR-IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
   4:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    4-fasteoi   idma64.8
   5:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    5-fasteoi   idma64.9
   8:          0          1  IR-IO-APIC    8-edge      rtc0
   9:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    9-fasteoi   acpi
  14:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   14-fasteoi   INT3452:00, INT3452:01, INT3452:02, INT3452:03
  27:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   27-fasteoi   idma64.0, i2c_designware.0
  28:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   28-fasteoi   idma64.1, i2c_designware.1
  29:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   29-fasteoi   idma64.2, i2c_designware.2
  30:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   30-fasteoi   idma64.3, i2c_designware.3
  31:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   31-fasteoi   idma64.4, i2c_designware.4
  32:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   32-fasteoi   idma64.5, i2c_designware.5
  33:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   33-fasteoi   idma64.6, i2c_designware.6
  34:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   34-fasteoi   idma64.7, i2c_designware.7
  35:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   35-fasteoi   idma64.10, pxa2xx-spi.10
  36:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   36-fasteoi   idma64.11, pxa2xx-spi.11
  37:          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   37-fasteoi   idma64.12, pxa2xx-spi.12
  39:    8139750          0  IR-IO-APIC   39-fasteoi   mmc0
  42:          0         52  IR-IO-APIC   42-fasteoi   mmc1
 120:          0          0  DMAR-MSI    0-edge      dmar0
 121:          0          0  DMAR-MSI    1-edge      dmar1
 128:   46595951    1380592  IR-PCI-MSI 344064-edge      xhci_hcd
 129:          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 294912-edge      ahci[0000:00:12.0]
 130:     367985     683938  IR-PCI-MSI 1048576-edge      enp2s0
 131:          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 1572864-edge      enp3s0
 132:     118381    1854434  IR-PCI-MSI 32768-edge      i915
 133:         38          0  IR-PCI-MSI 245760-edge      mei_me
 134:          0        158  IR-PCI-MSI 229376-edge      AudioHDA, AudioDSP
 NMI:       5668       5708   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:  220497637  222196331   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:       5668       5708   Performance monitoring interrupts
 IWI:       5223      78287   IRQ work interrupts
 RTR:          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
 RES:   37074108   66691486   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:     181736     343240   Function call interrupts
 TLB:      44525      46583   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:       3729       3496   Threshold APIC interrupts
 DFR:          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:       4381       4149   Machine check polls
 ERR:          0
 MIS:          0
 PIN:          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
 NPI:          0          0   Nested posted-interrupt event
 PIW:          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

and this is /proc/softirqs

```
                CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
      HI:      74033    1015476          0          0
   TIMER:   43883298   44090466          0          0
  NET_TX:      38094        175          0          0
  NET_RX:     682323    1006972          0          0
   BLOCK:     406480     482104          0          0
IRQ_POLL:          0          0          0          0
 TASKLET:        573       1381          0          0
   SCHED:   46527362   46739180          0          0
 HRTIMER:          0          0          0          0
     RCU:   15255825   14216607          0          0
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Is there a newer kernel available for you hardware? Some interrupt storm type issues with problematic USBs have been solved. You could try identifying something to "trigger" from, like an extreme number of interrupts per unit time, in a user defined task. Something in `/proc/interrupts` or `/proc/softirqs` or elsewhere in `/proc`.

Comment: Hi Doug, sadly there is no newer kernel available. I added the output of /proc/interrupts and /proc/softirqs above. Can you see anything? I don't understand what the numbers are saying. 
Any idea of how to bring the watchdog to do a force reboot in that case?

Comment: To clarify, I meant to look at them twice, during the issue, and calculate the differences in an attempt to isolate something that could be used as a "trigger".